# How to post data from flash form to PHP?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to parse an image file, but i get the 504 error. Normal data, like text or numbers its ok...

Answer (score 0):

I use ZendPHP to transfer Flash variables to PHP and then to a database.

Take a look at this forum thread: http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/tutorials/3421-actionscript-3-0-zend-amf.html